# Basic Equation question

Tags: computational-complexity

This is regarding algorith complexity, but that's not the point here.

I saw this resolution:

```
4( n/1,3 )² = 4/1,69 x n²
```

Could anyone clarify how is this equation is done? How can `4( n/1,3 )²` equals to `4/1,69 x n²`

I tried to reproduce but failed drastically.

```
4( n/1,3 )²  =  4 x n/1,3 x n/1,3
             =  4 x n²/1,69
             =  ?
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is wrong with $4 \times n^2/1.69 = 4/1.69 \times n^2$?

Answer (score 0):

$$ (a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab \\(1.3)^2=(1+0.3)^2=1+(0.3)^2+2(1)(0.3)\\(1.3)^2=1+0.09+0.6=1.69 \\so\\4(\frac{n}{1.3})^2=4*\frac{(n)^2}{(1.3)^2}=4*\frac{n^2}{1.69} $$

Comment: Thanks. But how can 4 * n²/1.69 = n² * 4/1.69

Comment: a*b=b*a   commutative law